# IMU Calibration with 16bit precision

Tags: c, precision, calibration, imu

I want to calibrate an IMU Sensor to a decimal precision. I'm programming in C.
I've defined a structure called accelerations with their variables x, y and z in **int16_t** format.

The raw values that I get (for the x, y and z Axis respectively) from the register reading(i.e. in accelerations) are for example: 218 -924 16312

The problem that I'm facing, is that by doing the calibration's multiplication

```
accelerations.x = (1*0.0006*(accelerations.x)-0.1681);
accelerations.y = (1*0.0006*(accelerations.y)+0.8076);
accelerations.z = (1*0.0006*(accelerations.z)-0.1698);
```

the values are rounded to integers, resulting in an output as follow: 0 0 9

What am I missing here?

Comment: Integer rounding is always floored, i.e. even 0,9999 becomes 0. Add 0,5 to all values before converting to int, and you shall have correct rounding. Consider scaling the values, to obtain better resolution at the numbers you care about.

Comment: Hi Morten. Thanks for the comment. What I want is to obtain decimal values, therefore I want to avoid the rounding.

Comment: If you store a value in a `int16_t` variable, you get rounding/chopping for free. No matter if you want it or not.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh, this was the error. I just made a new structure with float variables, instead of int16_t. What a Blunder did I made there!